# I want to send sensor data from MyRIO to XBee3 Mesh

Tags: sensors, uart, labview, data-transfer, xbee

I want to send sensor data from MyRIO to XBee3 Mesh. I have been looking at the XBee's documentation to check where the UART port is, but I have not found this simple information, instead, I found DIOs and PWM pins.

We tried to send data using the USB port and we were unable to do so.

Can anybody help us out with it? Any help, even just a direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

AIMS

Answer (score 0):

Page 11 of the [Digi XBee 3 RF Module documentation](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/pdfs/90001543.pdf) shows the following pins for the TTL-level UART:

```
UART pins                  XBee 3 Device pin number
                   micro-mount   surface-mount   through-hole
DOUT/DIO13              3               3               2
DIN/CONFIG/DIO14        4               4               3
CTS/DIO7               24              25              12
RTS/DIO6               27              29              16
```